# Accessing variable from properties file in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have properties file in my project where I have placed all the URLS and other configuration properties.

I have one URL which I want to use in `.xhtml` page. I have tried many things but no success.

below is my JSF page:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/mainlayout.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <div id="iFrameContainer">
        <iframe  width="100%" 
                 height="100%" 
                 frameborder="0" 
                 src="http://testURL">
        </iframe>
    </div>

  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

`testURL` is the place where I want to use the properties file URL parameter.

Comment: "I have tried many things but no success" for example?

Comment: previous commenter is right, see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `faces-config.xml` add:

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>package.name_of_properties_file</base-name>
  <var>props</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

And then, in the `facelets` file you can use it:

```
 <div id="iFrameContainer">
    <iframe  width="100%" 
             height="100%" 
             frameborder="0" 
             src="#{props['textUrl']}"
             >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: @thanks but what is 'msg' ?

Comment: @Talib excuse-me... it wa a typo. Now it's corrected